# Histogram Formatting

Tags: c++, format, histogram

I am writing a program to create a horizontal histogram from an array of type double data. I was able to get the program to display the boundaries of each sub-interval along with the correct number of asterisks. However, the data is not formatted.

Here's the part of the program responsible for the output:

```
// endpoints == the boundaries of each sub-interval
// frequency == the number of values which occur in a given sub-interval
for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
{
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
    cout << endPoints[i] << " to " << endPoints[i + 1] << ": ";
    for (int j = frequency[i]; j > 0; j--)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << " (" << frequency[i] << ")" << endl;
}
```

Here's what my output looks like:

```
0.00 to 3.90: *** (3)
3.90 to 7.80: * (1)
7.80 to 11.70: * (1)
11.70 to 15.60:  (0)
15.60 to 19.50: ***** (5)
```

Here's what I would like it to look like:

```
00.00 to 04.00: *** (3)
04.00 to 08.00: * (1)
08.00 to 12.00: * (1)
12.00 to 16.00:  (0)
16.00 to 20.00: ****** (6)
```

I've looked up C++ syntax and have found things like setw() and setprecision(). I tried to use both to format my histogram but have not been able to make it look like the model. I was hoping someone could tell me if I'm on the right track and, if so, how to implement setw() and/or setprecision() to properly format my histogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all numbers are in the [0,100) interval, what you want is a chain of manipulators like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::cout
        << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(5)
        << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed
        << 2.0
        << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which will output:

```
02.00
```

This is for a single value, you can easily adapt it to suit your needs.

You could, for instance, turn this into an operator and use it like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class FixedDouble {
public:
    FixedDouble(double v): value(v) {}
    const double value;
}

std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & stream, const FixedDouble &number) {
    stream
        << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(5)
        << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed
        << number.value
        << std::endl;

    return stream;
}

int main() {
    //...

    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        std::cout
            << FixedDouble(endPoints[i])
            << " to "
            << FixedDouble(endPoints[i + 1])
            << ": ";
    }

    for (int j = frequency[i]; j > 0; j--) {
        std::cout << "*";
    }
    std::cout << " (" << frequency[i] << ")" << std::endl;

    //...
}
```

Comment: My histogram needs to be able to handle all real numbers. Is it still possible to do this with manipulators?

Comment: Well, yes, you just have to tweak the `setw` value, which is the overall number of characters printed (including the padding zeroes/spaces and the decimal point) and the `setprecision` value, which is the number of decimal digits to keep.